# Swift 2 iOS 9 availability global var

Tags: ios, swift, compatibility

I am trying to make my iOS 9 app backwards compatible.
This is my AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    var window: UIWindow?

    static let connMngr = ConnMngr()

    static let appCtrl = AppCtrl()

    var contactStore = CNContactStore()
...
```

I cant seem to find a way how to check availability of iOS 9 before declaring the contactStore var.

Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking

Answer (score 4):

`Swift 2.0` introduced `availability` checking, you can check for feature availability in swift using:

```
if #available(iOS 9, *)  {
   // available
} else {
   // not available
}
```

Comment: I tied that already, you cant do an if statement outside a function

Comment: check this link https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking